# How to download a PDF from a great library voghDev / PdfViewPager through a URL and then store within the app in Android using java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf-generation, androidpdfviewer

**1)** I want to download the PDF using **voghDev/PdfViewPager** library through a **URL**.

**2)** The downloaded PDF should be stored in the users internal memory.

I am able to directly view the pdf from the url but unable to actually download it.

`RemotePDFViewPager remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(context, MyUrlContainingDownloadablePFDLink, this); remotePDFViewPager.setId(R.id.pdfViewPager);`

The XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/remote_pdf_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <es.voghdev.pdfviewpager.library.PDFViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pdfViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="480dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

By using the above code I can view the pdf from the link but cannot download it.

[Link to the library on Github](https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager)

**How do I download it ?**

Comment: Just in the same way you would download any file. Using DownloadManager for example.

Comment: `public void onSuccess(String url, String destinationPath)` Have you inspected `destinationPath` ?

Comment: I read this code and also tried implementing it but I cannot find a way to work it out. And also I cannot understand what this destinationPath actually means. Can you help me figure it out

Comment: As far as my understanding goes this function does not return anything so how can I store the pdf downloaded by providing its **url**  into a variable ? need some guidance :)

Comment: You should look what the value of destinationPath is to begin with. That is what i suggested. Could be that the downloaded file is already saved in that path was my idea.